# Чем отличается С++ от С# ?

Tags: c#, c++

И еще, на Microsoft Visual Studio на C# программируют?

Answer (score 11):

Если абстрагироваться от синтаксиса, то у C# и C++ есть несколько кардинальных отличий:

1. C# (также как и J#, VB# и проч.)
       работает поверх некой виртуальной
       машины которая называется dot NET
       Framework. То есть объектный код C#
       генерирует коды для виртуальной (а
       не физической машины).
       Соответственно, там где есть эта
       виртуальная машина объектник C#
       будет работать везде - это свойство
       называется кроссплатформенностью,
       частным следствием этого является то
       что размеры типов C# фиксированы.
       С++ собирает объектный код для
       конкретной платформы: Windows x86,
       Windows x64, Linux, Sparc и т.д.
       Причем везде размеры типов и
       [endianness - очередность битов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
       разные, так что при переносе кода
       между платформами постоянно
       возникают проблемы.
2. В С# автоматизирована проблема
           деаллокации объектов (т.н. сборщик
           мусора). В идеале прогер только
           создает объекты, а уже сборщик
           мусора сам разбирается кого и когда
           уничтожить. В С++ напротив проблема
           управления памятью вся возложена на
           прогера. Это в общем то целая наука
           как правильно управлять памятью,
           чтобы не было ее утечки.

Конечно, есть и более тонкие отличия - но это уже детали. Основные отличия я указал.

Comment: Осталось лишь добавить: "C#-один из самых прекрасных языков для сотворения кроссплатформенных приложений под Windows...ах!" =)

Comment: ^ да вы, сударь, шутник =)

Answer (score 7):

[Язык C# для разработчиков на языке С++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yyaad03b(v=vs.90).aspx)

> В следующей таблице содержится сравнение C# и C++ (где не используется /clr) в различных областях ... в этой таблице вы найдете важные различия между этими двумя языками.

В добавок: [различия между шаблонами языка C++ и универсальными шаблонами языка C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c6cyy67b.aspx).

Да, на Microsoft Visual Studio в основном на C# и программируют.

Answer (score 5):

C++ и C# — это два разных языка программирования с C-подобным синтаксисом.

[C#](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) — объектно-ориентированный язык программирования с автоматическим управлением памятью, предназначенный для программирования на платформе [.NET](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

[C++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) — кросс-платформенный язык программирования общего назначения, совместимый в большинстве случаев с [C](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста, откуда могу найти полные видеокурсы по C#?

Comment: @navi1893 лучше задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Wiki уже не та =)

Comment: попробуй поискать видеокурсы тут [www.fileshouse.com](http://www.fileshouse.com)

Answer (score 5):

Язык C++ - 2 плюса, а C# - 4 плюса :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ и C# - разные языки. C# более высокоуровневый. На нём удобнее всего программировать графический интерфейс. Но между этими языками большая пропасть: на C# очень сложно использовать библиотеки, предназначенные для `C++`. Также программы на C# требуют для своей работы установленный .NET Framework, версия которого зависит от используемой версии C#. На Windows Vista предустановлен .NET Framework 3.0, а на Windows 7 - 3.5. На Windows XP .NET Framework нужно устанавливать самому.

На языке C# необязательно писать именно на Visual Studio. Можно использовать любую IDE или даже обычный редактор, например блокнот.

Comment: > на C# очень сложно использовать библиотеки, предназначенные для C

    [DllImport("foo.dll")]
    public static extern int Bar(int baz);

Примерно [настолько](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) очень.

Comment: Я знаю про PInvoke, но когда писал это сообщение ещё не знал. Но всё равно это только для C, а ТС спрашивал про C++. К тому же загружать функции динамически (во время выполнения программы) таким образом не получится.

Comment: И правда, на даты я не посмотрел. Но не суть, тут, как бы, наполовину вики, уточнения приемлемы, надеюсь, всегда.

С C++ все, действительно, сложнее. Собственно, работать с библиотеками на нем сложно даже из C++ — различия в версии компилятора и все. Решают «переходником» на managed c++.

С динамической загрузкой библиотек все [просто](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx), делегат с `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` и `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` для, собственно, получения указателя.

Answer (score 2):

C# - объектно-ориентированный язык программирования с C подобным синтаксисом.

C++ - расширенная версия C. На данный момент есть более расширенная версия, точное название не скажу.

Visual Studio на данный момент поддерживает множество языков программирования, например PHP, Iron Python.

В бесплатном доступе есть редакторы для C# C++ [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) VBasic имеющие префикс Express. Их можно бесплатно скачать с сайта Microsoft, получив учетную запись MSDN.

Comment: > C++ - расширенная версия C.

Не соглашусь. С++ - это ДРУГОЙ язык с Си-подобным синтаксисом. Это раз. Два - существует множество языков, похожих на С. Это и С++, и C#, и Java... Из менее известных есть [D][1], который можно рассматривать как отдельную, улучшенную версию С++.

 [1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это другой язык.
Я бы сказал что Си встроен в C++.
Главная задача была в поддержке старого кода на Си, отсюда обязательная поддержка большинства концепций Си. 

И если можно писать код одного языка в другом без каких либо сложностей, значит это не другой язык.

Comment: @manking, компилятор С++ значительно строже, чем C. Далеко не все Си программы компилируются как C++.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте-ка и я дополню список.

Странно, что ещё никто не упомянул наибольшее различие: C++ — это небезопасный язык. В том смысле, что конструкции языка могут приводить к undefined behaviour, состоянию, в котором на поведение программы (а также компилятора) не даётся вовсе никаких гарантий. Получить такую ситуацию достаточно легко: доступ к массиву за пределами выделенной памяти, арифметическое переполнение, ошибочный `static_cast` приводят к ней.

C# же (за исключением кода, помещенного ключевым словом `unsafe`) — [безопасный](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safety)  [язык](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). В нём подобные ситуации исключены — за счёт дополнительных проверок, происходящих во время выполнения.