# Ошибка в Android studio c++: Type 'void' used in 'if' condition is not scalar

Tags: c++, android-studio

Я написал вот такой код и у меня возникает ошибка "Type 'void' used in 'if' condition is not scalar":

```
void (*ObjectDestroy)(void*);
void (*PLAYER)(void*);
class Ray {};
void (*PhysicsRaycast)(Ray, RaycastHit, float);
Ray (*ViewPointToRay)(Vector3);
void (*old_func)(void *instance);
void func(void *instance) {
    if (instance != NULL) {
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        if (!GameManagerLateUpdateHookInitialized) {
            GameManagerLateUpdateHookInitialized = true;
        }
        if (bool && PhysicsRaycast(ViewPointToRay(Vector3(0.5f, 1f, 0f)), raycastHit , 3f)) // Type 'void' used in 'if' condition is not scalar
        {
            ObjectDestroy(PLAYER);
        }
    }
old_func(instance);
}
```

Можно ли её исправить её исправить?

Update

Исправил сам
PhysicsRaycast это bool

Comment: Vector3 и RaycastHit это отдельные файлы
Vector3
`class Vector3 {
public:
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3 (float sx, float sy = 0.0, float sz = 0.0):
            x(sx), y(sy), z(sz) { }
    Vector3() {}
    ~Vector3() {}
};`
RaycastHit 
`#pragma once

#include "Vector3.h"
class Collider;

struct RaycastHit
{
 Vector3 m_Point;
 float m_Distance;
 Vector3 m_Normal;
 Collider* m_Collider;
};`

Comment: Как вы хотите, в каком случае должен вызываться `ObjectDestroy` в зависимости от `PhysicsRaycast`? Что должно произойти в `PhysicsRaycast`, чтобы была вызвана `ObjectDestroy`?

Comment: Это код на C#
`if (bool && Physics.Raycast(ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 1f, 0f)), out raycastHit, 3f))
        {
            UnityEngine.GameObject.Destroy(player);
            bool = false;
        }
`
Я забыл написать bool

Comment: Цитата : "Язык C++ - 2 плюса, а C# - 4 плюса :) " https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75188/Чем-отличается-С-от-С

Answer (score 2):

А что собственно непонятно? Вам же компилятор прямо говорит, что ваша функция `PhysicsRaycast` возвращает `void` который вы пытаетесь обработать в `if`, хотя в `if` могут обрабатываться только скаляры (int, bool и т.д.)

Comment: А как тогда можно разместить void в if. При void вместе с bool возникает другая ошибка.
"Binary operator '&&' can't be appiled to the expressions of type 'bool' and 'void'"
Этот код я пишу на подобии другого на C#.

Comment: @geokar чтобы не задавать глупых вопросов ознакомтесь, пожалуйста, с базовым устройством языка